# How to separated zero with point in my bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, math, logic

My script

```
 echo -n "number 1 : ";
 read bil1
 echo -n "number 2 :";
 read bil2
 jlh=$(echo $bil1 + $bil2 |bc -l |sed -e 's/^\./0./' -e 's/^-\./-0' -e 's/\.0*$//');
 echo " Your result : $bil1 + $bil2 = $jlh";
```

if I input " 100000 " in $bil1 and "100000 " in $bil2 , the result is " 200000 ".

I want :

```
Your result : 100000 + 100000 = 200.000
```

how to separated zero with " . " for that result from 200000 to 200.000 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript/2901298#2901298 shows how to do it in Javascript, but I don't think `sed` supports the regexp extensions that this depends on.

Comment: Not a duplicate; in that question, he wanted to remove a trailing decimal portion. In this question, he seems to want a grouping character added to the result.

Comment: your sed command will change `-.333` to `-0333`

Answer (score 3):

If your libc supports it, the `'` flag in a `printf` specifier will add groupers to a number.

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=en_US printf "%'d\n" 100000
100,000
$ LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR printf "%'d\n" 100000
100 000
$ LC_NUMERIC=de_DE printf "%'d\n" 100000
100.000
$ LC_NUMERIC=bn_IN printf "%'d\n" 100000
1,00,000
```

Comment: thats true, but if I input 0.2 + 0.3, the result is not valid ???
can you help me again?

Comment: No, because bash doesn't do floats.

Comment: but , any command to do floats them ??? .
Please help me ...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+floating+point

Comment: just run the printf on variable jlh like Ignacio has mentioned and it will work.

Comment: but, if i use printf, my script is only use with integers number, i want use printf for not integers number...
Please help me ???